# Windows Forms : Почему-то не заходит в оператор if

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Суть задачи заключается в том , чтобы пользователь из checkedlistbox выбрал 9 чисел из которых в будущем будет создан массив 3 на 3 и будет выведен в DataGridViev,но почему-то при выборе 9 чисел  вызывается MessageBox который говорит "Выберите ровно 9 чисел" , хотя условие говорит то что вызываться MessageBox должен при выборе не 9 чисел.
Т.е. оно банально не заходит в простое условие.
код :

````
        if ((checkedListBox1->SelectedItems->Count) != 9)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Введіть рівно 9 елементів");
        }
        else
        {
            int p = 0;
            int mas[3][3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    mas[i][j] = Convert::ToInt16(checkedListBox1->CheckedItems[p]);
                    p++;
                }
            }
            switch (comboBox1->SelectedIndex)
            {
            case -1:
                MessageBox::Show("Choosing error");
                break;
            case 0:
                dataGridView1->RowCount = 3;
                dataGridView1->ColumnCount = 3;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value = mas[i][j].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }```
````

Comment: `SelectedItems` != `CheckedItems`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkedListBox1->CheckedItems->Count != 9)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Введіть рівно 9 елементів");
        }
```

Заменил SelectedItems на CheckedItems